# Appending Text To the Existing First Line with Sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, awk

I have a data that looks like this (FASTA format). Note that 
in comes with block of 2 ">" header and the sequence.

```
>SRR018006
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGN
>SRR018006
ACCCGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

What I want to do is to append a text (e.g. "foo" in the > header)
yielding:

```
>SRR018006-foo
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGN
>SRR018006-foo
ACCCGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Is there a way to do that using SED? Preferably inline modifying
the original file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do what you're looking for.

```
sed -ie 's/^\(>.*\)/\1-foo/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

since judging from your previous post, you are also experienced using awk: here's an awk solution.

```
# awk '/^>/{print $0"-foo";next}1' file
>SRR018006-foo
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGN
>SRR018006-foo
ACCCGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

# awk '/^>/{print $0"-foo";next}1' file > temp
# mv temp file
```

if you insist on sed

```
# sed -e '/^>/s/$/-foo/' file
```

Comment: Despite your negative tone, I'd say your suggestion with sed is much cleaner than the other two using awk, and probably much more efficient.